# Big O Notation - input size

Tags: input, big-o

I am reading a blog abt big O notation on topcoder.
https://www.topcoder.com/community/data-science/data-science-tutorials/computational-complexity-section-1/

I have come across the below paragraph

> Formal notes on the input size
>
> What exactly is this "input size" we started to talk about? In the
>   formal  definitions this is the size of the input written in some
>   fixed finite alphabet (with at least 2 "letters"). For our needs, we
>   may consider this alphabet to be the numbers 0..255. Then the "input
>   size" turns out to be exactly the size of the input file in bytes.

can anyone please explain what does this statement say?

> it is the size of the input written in some
>   fixed finite alphabet (with at least 2 "letters"). For our needs, we
>   may consider this alphabet to be the numbers 0..255.

Answer (score 0):

The statement is about the fundamental representation of information using symbols. The more symbols you use (the bigger the alphabet is), the more information you can represent with less characters although you can represent everything with just two "letters", i.e. one bit of information per character. Using the numbers 0..255 is equivalent to using 8 bit, i.e. one byte (2^8=256).

In computer programming, you normally use bytes but in theoretical computer science bits are used as they have the same capabilities (you just need more of them) and it makes proofs easier to write.

Answer (score 0):

This statement means the following. You have to represent the input to process it by the algorithm, i.e. you have to "write it down". You can write the input down with letters (=symbols). The number of symbols have to be finite (or else you or the algorithm can not understand it), i.e. they comes from a *fixed finite alphabet* (=set of possible symbols). The size of input is that how many letters did you used to write down the input.

In the example mentioned in the text there is written that the alphabet contains the numbers between 0 and 255. This means that each letter can be written with an ASCII character. So, you can write down your input with ASCII characters. Each ASCII character can be stored in one byte, i.e. the size of input (=number of ASCII characters) is the number of bytes.

Answer (score 0):

Let me explain by example.

Let's take, say, the factorization (sub)problem: given number `n` (not prime), find any of its divisors different from `1` and `n`. Clearly, we need to check at most `sqrt(n)` numbers to find one. Thus it seems to be a subpolynomial problem. Why it is considered a hard nut to crack then? That's because we usually need only `log(n)` digits to write down `n`, and we naturally want to resolve the problems which are "easy to write down". But although `sqrt(n)` may seem a little when compared to `n`, it's too much for us when compared to `log(n)`.

That is the point why we need to say a word about "input alphabet" before talking of problem's complexity.